# Why am I getting message about failed altering table while I am only mapping classes to tables at test launch?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, testng

At the start of tests, I am mapping many tables from Oracle DB to java classes. Just now I am running only one test query and it runs OK. (Thank SO!)

I have turned on the messages and at the stage of context creation and tables mapping I see not only many successful table findings but in the end, several messages such as:

```
TST-[2020/12/02 23:58:53.715] hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table CIS_LOKAL_ROLE_AAA add KOD_LOKAL_ROLA_AAA varchar2(10 char) not null
TST-[2020/12/02 23:58:53.715] hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column

TST-[2020/12/02 23:58:53.881] hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table P01_OPRAVNENI add constraint FK_c0cufehvbvpf9y3dh0fcjrhak foreign key (ID_OBJEKTU) references R01_RIZENI
TST-[2020/12/02 23:58:53.881] hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate ORA-02298: cannot validate (SPR.FK_C0CUFEHVBVPF9Y3DH0FCJRHAK) - parent keys not found
```

Why does hibernate want to alter tables at the time of mapping?

Please, note, that there are questions about the similar messages here on SO, but they touch situations when the tables really are to be altered and fail. While I don't want to alter them, the only query is about a counting query, and that is successful and comes after the problems I am writing about.

---

testng class:

```
@Test//(enabled = false)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={ "classpath:beans_sets/UhradyForIns.xml"/* , "classpath:beans_sets/mvc-config.xml"*/})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="transactionManager", defaultRollback=false)
@DirtiesContext(classMode= DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class OdeslatJakobyAutomatickyUhraduTest extends TestBaseWithProperties {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OdeslatJakobyAutomatickyUhraduTest.class);
    @Autowired( required = true )
    U01UhradaBaseJpaDaoForTesting dao;
    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void odeslat(){
        if(dao == null){
            Assert.fail("Null context.");
        }
        dao.setRecordsForSending();
        Reporter.log(new String("Number of uhrady to send = "+dao.countUhradyToSend()));
        //List<U01Uhrada> uhrady = dao.findUhradyProPoslani();
    }
}

public class U01UhradaBaseJpaDaoForTesting {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="SprUnit")
    protected EntityManager em;

    void setRecordsForSending(){

    }
    long countUhradyToSend(){
        QU01Uhrada uh = QU01Uhrada.u01Uhrada;

        JPAQuery jq = new JPAQuery(em);
        jq.from(uh);
        jq.where(uh.preposlano.eq(U01UhradaPreposlanoEnum.K_PREPOSLANI.asKod()));
        return jq.count();
    }

}

public class TestBaseWithProperties extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
    {
        //---------------------------------- setting paths
        // absolute path up to main-app
        String mainApp = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String apv = mainApp.substring(0, mainApp.lastIndexOf("\\"));

        System.setProperty("main.app", mainApp);
        System.setProperty("main.web.webinf", apv + "/main-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF");
        System.setProperty("spr.root.dir", mainApp + "/work");


        // -------------------------------------- setting DB
        System.setProperty("database.driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        System.setProperty("database.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oradb2.companyname.com:1534:INPD12");
        System.setProperty("database.user", "user");
        System.setProperty("database.password", "pass");
    }
}
```

UhradyForIns.xml:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/spr-properties.xml" />


<!--    Database setting -->
<!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:beans_sets/database-test.properties"/>-->
<bean id="dataSourceBean"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="file:${main.app}/src/test/resources/beans_sets/persistence-spr-test.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SprUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Automatic Transaction Participation-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="U01UhradaBaseJpaDaoForTesting" class="amcssz.spr.srv.main.jobs.U01UhradaBaseJpaDaoForTesting"/>
```

persistence-spr-test.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="SprUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" >
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/spr-db</jta-data-source>

    <class>amcssz.spr.srv.main.entity.P01Opravneni</class>
    ....
    <class>amcssz.spr.srv.main.entity.cis.CisLokalRoleAaa</class>
    
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
<!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The entities of the problem tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CIS_LOKAL_ROLE_AAA")
public class CisLokalRoleAaa extends AbstractCisEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1302716162506083142L;

    @Id  //that column exists in the table
    @Column(name="KOD_LOKAL_ROLA_AAA", unique=true, nullable=false, length=10)
    private String kodLokalRole;


    @Column(name="KOD_PRACOVISTE", length=10)
    private String kodPracoviste;

    public CisLokalRoleAaa() {
    }

    public String getKodLokalRole() {
        return kodLokalRole;
    }

    public void setKodLokalRole(String kodLokalRole) {
        this.kodLokalRole = kodLokalRole;
    }

    public String getKodPracoviste() {
        return kodPracoviste;
    }

    public void setKodPracoviste(String kodPracoviste) {
        this.kodPracoviste = kodPracoviste;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="P01_OPRAVNENI")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "KOD_TYP_OBJEKTU", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class P01Opravneni extends AbstractUpdateable implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3009052816433258266L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="P01_OPRAVNENI_IDR02OPRAVNENIRIZENI_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_P01_OPRAVNENI")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="P01_OPRAVNENI_IDR02OPRAVNENIRIZENI_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="ID_P01_OPRAVNENI", unique=true, nullable=false, precision=22)
    private Long idP01Opravneni;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="DATINS")
    private Date datins;
    
    @Column(name="JE_AKTUALNI", nullable=false, precision=1)
    private Boolean jeAktualni;

    @Column(name="VYMAHAC", nullable=false, length=44)
    private String vymahac;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="KOD_TYP_OBJEKTU", referencedColumnName="KOD_OBJEKT",nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private CisObjekt cisObjekt;
    
    @Column(name="KOD_TYP_OBJEKTU",nullable=false, insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private String kodTypObjektu;
    
    @Column(name="ID_OBJEKTU", nullable=false)
    private Long idObjektu;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="KOD_PRACOVISTE", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private CisPracovisteCssz cisPracovisteCssz;
    
    @Column(name="KOD_PRACOVISTE", precision=10)
    private String kodPracoviste;
    
    @Column(name="prevzato_do")
    private Date prevzatoDo; 

    public Long getIdObjektu() {
        return idObjektu;
    }
    public void setIdObjektu(Long idObjektu) {
        this.idObjektu = idObjektu;
    }

    public String getKodTypObjektu() {
        return kodTypObjektu;
    }

    public void setKodTypObjektu(String kodTypObjektu) {
        this.kodTypObjektu = kodTypObjektu;
    }
    

    public P01Opravneni() {
    }
    
    public Long getIdP01Opravneni() {
        return idP01Opravneni;
    }
    public void setIdP01Opravneni(Long idP02Opravneni) {
        this.idP01Opravneni = idP02Opravneni;
    }
    
    public Date getDatins() {
        return datins;
    }
    public void setDatins(Date datins) {
        this.datins = datins;
    }
    
    public Boolean getJeAktualni() {
        return this.jeAktualni;
    }

    public void setJeAktualni(Boolean jeAktualni) {
        this.jeAktualni = jeAktualni;
    }

    public String getVymahac() {
        return this.vymahac;
    }

    public void setVymahac(String vymahac) {
        this.vymahac = vymahac;
    }

    public CisObjekt getCisObjekt() {
        return this.cisObjekt;
    }

    public void setCisObjekt(CisObjekt cisObjekt) {
        this.cisObjekt = cisObjekt;
    }
    
    public CisPracovisteCssz getCisPracovisteCssz() {
        return this.cisPracovisteCssz;
    }

    public void setCisPracovisteCssz(CisPracovisteCssz cisPracovisteCssz) {
        this.cisPracovisteCssz = cisPracovisteCssz;
    }
    
    public String getKodPracoviste() {
        return kodPracoviste;
    }
    
    public void setKodPracoviste(String kodPracoviste) {
        this.kodPracoviste = kodPracoviste;
    }
    public Date getPrevzatoDo() {
        return prevzatoDo;
    }
    public void setPrevzatoDo(Date prevzatoDo) {
        this.prevzatoDo = prevzatoDo;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Did you happen to change the kodLocalRole nullable to false?

Comment: Yes, it is false in the table, too.

Comment: I meant did it previously used to be _true_  before you ran the application again?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thank you, I understand that there could be some discrepancies that really do not allow to update some tables. But even if there are some, the question is different - why hibernate wants to update them while mapping? Really, it is maybe even good that these discrepancies allow us to notice that hibernate tries to do something it shouldn't.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha And as for the second problem table, hibernate reports problems with some columns that exist neither in Entity nor in the table.

Comment: As for  kodLocalRole, it is always non-nullable. Oh! I have an idea - maybe, that permanent file has some properties that change tables? I know there exist one that can do it, I mean drop and create the tables. Maybe, there are others with similar qualities??